# ATTN PhoneGap/Cordova project contributors: Issue with deviceready callback being called in 2 distinct ways

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

The first time I load up my cordova app, the breakpoint at line 130 (please refer to attached image) gets hit. It calls the deviceready delegate function and everything is fine.

[image: Debugger screenshot]

I navigate to another page and then when I do a window.history.back() (back to original page), the deviceready event is fired in a different way (see breakpoint on 135). There is no DeviceInfo which makes the Cordova "not available". Note the following excerpt from cordova.js:

```
Cordova.available = DeviceInfo.uuid != undefined;
```

Which also means, even though I'm waiting for the deviceready event to call Cordova.exec, it will always fail. Here is another excerpt from cordova.js which illustrates why.

```
Cordova.exec = function() { 
    if (!Cordova.available) {
        alert("ERROR: Attempting to call Cordova.exec()"
              +" before 'deviceready'. Ignoring.");
        return;
    }
```

So my question is; why are there 2 ways cordova will call the deviceready and why does it use the 'dud' way when I arrive at the page by going back on my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be version 1.5 or earlier.  The loading and firing of deviceReady has significantly changed in more recent versions.

Comment: Excellent - this 'bug' no longer occurs after upgrading to 1.8. Thanks.